# iOS text input issue: the caret flies in

Tags: ios, caret, textinput

When I type in words, the caret of the textfield flies in.

And I noticed that , this situation only occurs the the first time.
I think it is a `init` issue,

[image: bug]

If I assign a frame to the caret at first, may be OK.

And i saw the issue on Ever Notes ,too.
[image]

I think , `caretRect(for:)` method of `UITextInput` is related.

How to solve it? Any good ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this question I noticed the same thing happening in my app, and a quick & hacky way to get rid of the animation was to put these two lines in my `viewWillAppear`:

```
self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
```

Comment: Usually it happens when you call these methods when an animation is in progress.

Comment: Better to put it in `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: Updated the answer ;)